# Density points and family of Borel sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Let $x \in \mathbb R^n$, $s>0$ and $\{C_r\}_{0<r<s}$ be a family of borel sets such that $B(x, \alpha r) \subset C_r \subset B(x, \beta r)$ for some fixed $0< \alpha < \beta$. Show that if $E$ is a Lebesgue measurable set and $t \in \{0,1\}$ then  $$\lim_{r \to 0^{+}} \frac{\lambda(E \cap C_r)}{\lambda(C_r)}=t \Leftrightarrow \lim_{r \to 0^{+}} \frac{\lambda(E \cap B(x,r))}{\omega_n r^n}=t$$
> But can be fails for some $t \in (0,1)$.

For see the limits i try to use the monotonicity of the measure and a change of variable e.g $t=\alpha r$, but i cant conclude. I think to i can study these problem via cases and using the theorem of lebesgue density points of $E$.

EDIT: I can conclude the case when $t=0$ but the case when $t=1$ not work with the change of variable, topologically i understand what happen, but i cant justify.

Any hint or help will be very grateful.

Comment: The first sentence seems incomplete or at least non-grammatical ("show that" doesn't fit where you have placed it -- maybe a missing sentence period?) and $A$ probably should be $E.$ Also, you haven't said what $\omega_n$ is, which appears in the 2nd equality. Finally, just to be a bit more precise, "But fails if $t \in (0,1)$" probably means "But for each $t \in (0,1)$ the logical equivalence can fail" (i.e. failure CAN occur, and not just for SOME such value of $t$ but for EACH such value of $t).$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro yes i mistake in the redaction, and $\omega_n$ denotes the $n-$dimensional lebesgue measure of the unitary ball

Comment: thanks for the aclarations

Comment: Continuing with my remark about what "fail" means here, there's an ambiguity as to whether the failure for each $0<t<1$ can occur for each such family of Borel sets (and measurable set $E$ and point $x),$ OR given $0<t<1$ it is possible to find such a family of Borel sets (and measurable set $E$ and point $x)$ such that the logical equivalence fails. I suspect the intended meaning is the latter (i.e. first pick $0<t<1,$ then we can find appropriate Borel sets and a measurable set $E$ and a point $x$ such that the logical equivalence fails).

Comment: The $t=1$ case follows from the $t=0$ case if you consider $\Bbb R^n\setminus E$ instead of $E$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FShrike has already pointed out in the comments that the case $t=1$ follows from $t=0$ by replacing $E$ with $\mathbb R^n\backslash E$.

To obtain counterexamples for $t\in (0,1)$, we can argue as follows.  The trick will be realizing that the condition $$B(x, \alpha r) \subset C_r \subset B(x, \beta r)$$ means we only really have to consider a discrete set of scales. We'll let $x=0$ and $s=1$, as all the ideas easily generalize.

For any set $A\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and $r>0$, denote by $rA$ the set $rA=\{ra\mid a\in A\}$. Let $B=B(0,1)$ be the unit ball.

Let $S\subseteq B\backslash \frac{1}{2}B$ be any measurable subset of measure $\lambda (S) \in (0,\lambda(B\backslash \frac{1}{2}B))$.

Let $$E=\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k}S,$$

and define $C=S\cup \frac{1}{2}B$.

Since $\lambda(E)=\lambda(C\cap E)=\lambda(B\cap E)\in (0,\lambda(B))$, and $\lambda(C)<\lambda(B)$, we have
$$0<\frac{\lambda(B\cap E)}{\lambda(B)}<\frac{\lambda(C\cap E)}{\lambda(C)}<1.$$

Moreover, for each $k\in\mathbb N$, it is easy to see from the scale invariant nature of our construction that

$$\frac{\lambda(\frac{1}{2^k}B\cap E)}{\lambda(\frac{1}{2^k}B)}= \frac{\lambda(B\cap E)}{\lambda(B)}$$
and
$$\frac{\lambda(\frac{1}{2^k}C\cap E)}{\lambda(\frac{1}{2^k}C)}= \frac{\lambda(C\cap E)}{\lambda(C)}.$$

Now, for each $r>0$ we define $k_r:=\lfloor\log_2\frac{1}{r}\rfloor$, so that $r\leq \frac{1}{2^{k_r}}<2r$, and define $C_r:=\frac{1}{2^{k_r}}C$.  Then $C_r$ contains $\frac{1}{2^{k_r+1}}B\supseteq \frac{r}{2}B$ and is contained in $\frac{1}{2^{k_r}}B\subseteq 2rB$, and so satisfies the requirements.

But then $$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\lambda(C_r\cap E)}{\lambda(C_r)}=\frac{\lambda (C\cap E)}{\lambda(C)}=:t\in (0,1)$$
(in fact the expression is constant in $r$), whereas for the subsequence $r_k=\frac{1}{2^k}$ we have
$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{\lambda(r_kB\cap E)}{\lambda(r_kB)}=\frac{\lambda (B\cap E)}{\lambda(B)}\neq t.$$

Finally, note that we can compute $t$ explicitly as $$t=\frac{\lambda(C\cap E)}{\lambda(C)}=\frac{\lambda(E)}{\lambda(C)} = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{nk}}\lambda(S)}{\lambda(S)+\frac{1}{2^n}\lambda(B)} = \frac{\left(\frac{2^n}{2^n-1}\right)\lambda(S)}{\lambda(S)+\frac{1}{2^n}\lambda(B)} = \frac{\frac{2^n}{2^n-1}}{1+\frac{\lambda(B)}{2^n\lambda(S)}},$$
so $t$ varies between $0$ and $1$ as $\lambda(S)$ varies between $0$ and $\lambda(B\backslash \frac{1}{2}B)$, hence we obtain counterexamples for all $t\in (0,1)$.